# running sonarqube 6.7.1 on Ubuntu Server 16.04 using provided deb-files fails

Tags: sonarqube, ubuntu-16.04

I'm unable to get the latest Sonarqube up and running on Ubuntu 16.04.
Installation was done using the deb provided by http://sonar-pkg.sourceforge.net

After a first cursory glance it seems that the installation routine sets up Sonarqube to run as user "root", whereas Elastisearch - which is mandatory - refuses to be started as "root".

Has anybody been able to set this up properly (i.e. running as a non-root user) and can point me to the respective documentation?

Thanks.

Comment: According to https://github.com/Godin/sonar-native-packages/blob/9698a390dd1975bd4127ad18855221b10c5254e0/deb/debian/sonar.postinst#L8-L10 and https://github.com/Godin/sonar-native-packages/blob/9698a390dd1975bd4127ad18855221b10c5254e0/deb/debian/sonar.init#L36 it creates and uses `sonar` user.

Answer (score 0):

First, navigate to the install folder >  ex: /opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/bin/linux-x86-64.

Then open the sonar.sh file in that folder using vim, nano commands etc.

Then uncomment the line which reads "RUN_AS_USER=" which is around line number 48.

change the line to "RUN_AS_USER=sonar"

restart your system, start the sonarqube server. You should be able to run your server.